# Added values to associative array with for loop gone after the loop PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I've two for loops that both create an associative array. I need to add the second array to the first array. This is a simple version of my first array

```
  'location' => 'some location' 
  'color' => 'some color'
  'data' => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => 1
      'name' => 'Name'
      'date' => 'some date'
  'qty' => null
```

The code that creates the first array:

```
$data = [];
$addedData = array();
foreach ($dataColors as $dataColor) {
    foreach ($existingData as $ed) {
        if ($ed['location_id'] === $location && $ed['color_id'] === $dataColor && !in_array($ed['species_id'], $addedData)) {
            array_push($addedData, $ed['species_id']);
            $data[] = array(
                'location' => $ed['location_id'],
                'color' => $ed['color_id'],
                'data' => $app['data_manager']->findOne(array('id' => $ed['species_id'])),
                'qty' => NULL
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need to add the second array to the `qty` key for each created array. This is what I tried:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $newData = [];
    foreach ($dataFromDatabase as $dfd) {
        if ($value['location'] === $dfd['location_id'] && $value['color'] === $dfd['color_id'] && $value['data']['id'] === $dfd['id']) {
            $newData[] = array(
                'week' => (int)date('W', strtotime($dfd['date'])),
                'qty' => (int)$dfd['qty']
            );
        }
    }
    $value[$key]['qty'] = $newData; 
    var_dump($value); // this schows the that the data is added to the array
}
var_dump($data); // this doesn't show the added data
```

How is it possible that the data added to the array isn't added after the for loop but inside the for loop it is?

Comment: foreach works on a _copy_ of the values, overwriting $value inside the loop, will not affect the original array. How to work around that using references, is explained on the manual page for foreach. Direct manipulation of `$data` itself is also on option, then you need to specify the correct keys to address the correct element.

Comment: `$value[$key]['qty'] = $newData;` makes little sense in that place, did you mean `$data[$key]['qty'] = $newData;` there to begin with?

Comment: You're right! I've struggled big time with this problem and you just solve my problem within one second. Thank you so much! @CBroe

Comment: If you answer the question I can approve your answer! @CBroe

Comment: Questions where there’s just a tiny mistake like this, should rather not be answered, but closed as “caused by a typo”. This is a Q&A site, but chances that this is going to help future readers are rather slim, because it is a unique situation, and not something that “translates” well to other problems people might have with such loops.